# How to convert json object's value to integer?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to submit a form of AngularJs application. 
And this what I have set the value to privacy.

`$scope.data.privacy = angular.toJson({'privacy': response.privacy});`

While submitting the form, It post privacy like this

```
{"privacy":{"sex":"2","birthday":"1","relationshipstatus":"2"}}
```

But I just need the object value as integer. i.e.

```
{"privacy":{"sex":2,"birthday":1,"relationshipstatus":2}}
```

How can I convert json object's value to integer?

Comment: And how does the `response.privacy` object look like?

Comment: This sounds like a server issue. Please be more specific. ALso doesn't really make sense needing to have a scope item as json string

Comment: That is in object looks like   Object  { sex :"2", birthday :"1", relationshipstatus:"2"}

Comment: when you post and get anythings from server it's come to simple plane text format. Network not understand any typecasting. so We apply typecasting after get data on server side or client side.

Answer (score 1):

JSON can handle numbers as follow:

```
{
    "TheObject":{
        "TheProperty":5
    }
}
```

If your property was doublequoted then it's a string else it's a numeric, boolean (`true` and `false` values), `null` or just something that cause parse error.

So instead of this

```
{"privacy":{"sex":"2","birthday":"1","relationshipstatus":"2"}}
```

use

```
{"privacy":{"sex":2,"birthday":1,"relationshipstatus":2}}
```

See http://json.org/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
parseInt("2", 10)
```

?

You need to recurse through the `response.privacy` object and call `parseInt` on all numeric strings.

And always [make sure that you call `parseInt` with 2 arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).